# Resize and crop image with CSS

Tags: html, css

I'd like to resize and crop an image of unknown dimensions, just with css. The image should be resized/cropped to completely fill a container of known dimensions, cutting off as little of the image as possible.

Also, if an image is cropped then I'd like to determine, for example, that the center of the image should be shown, not the top left.

I made a jsfiddle illustrating the issue: http://jsfiddle.net/q9jFx/

I can, for example, set image width to 100%, but that doesn't work if the image is wider than it is tall.

```
.container { width: 180px; height: 160px; overflow: hidden; border:red solid 2px }
.container img { width:100%}

<div class="container">
     <img src="the_src" alt="alt" />
</div>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The only way you can achieve this only using css is to use the CSS `background` property combining it with the `background-size` and `background-position` properties.

**SEE THIS [FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/q9jFx/22/)**

More information for these properties :
[background-position](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/background-position)
[background-size](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/background-size)

HTML:

```
<div class="container" style="background-image:url(http://www.recipestap.com/wp-content/plugins/wp-o-matic/cache/af4e1_ap.jpg)"></div>
<div class="container" style="background-image:url(http://3.bp.blogspot.com/-LAfvYIuz6c4/UpQxIe-FlmI/AAAAAAAAAcE/DVeCw1W6Yu4/s320/Eggless+Mini+Apple+Pie.JPG)"></div>
```

CSS:

```
.container { 
    width: 180px;
    height: 160px;
    border:red solid 2px;

    /* add following */
    background-size:cover;
    background-position:50% 50%;
}
```

---

**ADDITIONAL INFORMATION**

If you realy need the `<img>` tag for SEO reasons or other, you will need JS to face all the cases you may come through.

**CASE 1 :** image ratio is wider than container
Use `height:100%;` and `width:auto;` then you will need JS again to center the image in the container.

**CASE 2 :** image ratio is heigher than the container
Use `width:100%;` and `height:auto;` then JS or `display:table;`/`display:table-cell` to verticaly center the image in container.

I have used this technique on some projects but it is pretty heavy compared to the `background` CSS technique.

Comment: Thanks. This works. I used: background-position: center center;  instead of 50% 50%. Same results.

Answer (score 1):

You can set Image width and Height

```
### please Try It: http://jsfiddle.net/q9jFx/3/
```

Comment: That stretches the image instead of cropping it.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of an `<img>` you could give the div a background and set `background-size: cover`.

css:

`background-image: url("yourimage");
    background-size:cover;
    background-position:center center;`

Answer (score 1):

If you don't need to necessarily use the image tag, using the image as a background for the container can easily do what you want.

**Jsfiddle sample: http://jsfiddle.net/zEP9L/**

HTML:

```
<p>Don't want the white space. Instead, should crop width to fill complete container.</p>
<div class="container">
     <img src="http://www.recipestap.com/wp-content/plugins/wp-o-matic/cache/af4e1_ap.jpg" alt="alt" />
</div>

<p>This looks ok, but would like to control the crop - eg show the center of the image, not the top</p>

<div class="container">
     <img src="http://3.bp.blogspot.com/-LAfvYIuz6c4/UpQxIe-FlmI/AAAAAAAAAcE/DVeCw1W6Yu4/s320/Eggless+Mini+Apple+Pie.JPG" alt="alt" />
</div>

<p>This is an alternative option</p>
<div class="container" id="something">
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.container { width: 180px; height: 160px; overflow: hidden; border:red solid 2px }
.container img { width:100%}

#something {
    background-image: url("http://3.bp.blogspot.com/-LAfvYIuz6c4/UpQxIe-FlmI/AAAAAAAAAcE/DVeCw1W6Yu4/s320/Eggless+Mini+Apple+Pie.JPG");
    background-size: cover;
    background-position: center center;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use `clip()` an old CSS rule http://tympanus.net/codrops/2013/01/16/understanding-the-css-clip-property/ , but it is easy for known image size .

For unknown image size, but known container size, you can use `line-height: /* height of container */;` and `text-align:center;`  to basicly center a single  inline element in this container.

The single image then can be set with : `vertical-align:middle;` and negative margin to virtually reduce its size , lets say : `margin:-50%;`.

For image too big in first place, use min or max width height to reduce their size.

```
.container {
    width: 180px;
    height: 160px;
    overflow: hidden;
    border:red solid 2px
}
.container {
    line-height:160px;
    text-align:center;
}
.container img {
    vertical-align:middle;
    margin: -50%;
    min-width:100%;
    max-height:150%;
}
```

DEMO :  http://jsfiddle.net/q9jFx/27/

*a few other demo if this makes you curious : http://codepen.io/gcyrillus/pen/etxky , http://codepen.io/gcyrillus/pen/BdtEj , http://codepen.io/gcyrillus/pen/hyAmd (3 different test of zooming/cropping img) , within a basic slider http://codepen.io/gc-nomade/pen/Hdpku , test imgvs bg http://codepen.io/gcyrillus/pen/wsjBJ*

Answer (score 0):

There is a one way I can think of (maybe there are others?). Using negative `translateY(-50%)`:

```
.container {
    width: 180px;
    height: 160px;
    overflow: hidden;
    border: red solid 2px;
    position: relative;
}
.container img {
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    top: 50%;
    width: 100%;
    -webkit-transform: translateY(-50%); 
}
```

#### Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/q9jFx/4/

So the trick is to set image positioned relatively to a container at the center (top and left 50%), and then move the image with translateY(-50%)`.

[Support](http://caniuse.com/#feat=transforms2d) is pretty good too. It's IE9+ (use -ms prefix for IE9) and all modern browsers.

Comment: That still leaves the extra white space for the wide image: http://jsfiddle.net/q9jFx/5/ It has just centered the image instead of making it bigger and then cropping off some of the width.

Answer (score 0):

What you want to do is

Overflow:hidden, the parent (container) element.

transform: scale(x), the img element

You can add object-position: x% x%, to the img element to move it around

For tidiness (on the img element):
Object-fit: cover;
aspect-ratio: 1/1;