# CSS: keep aspect ratio when rendering an image

Tags: html, css, image

a simple CSS problem:

- Display animal pictures in the grey box as shown in the picture below
- Image size must be 150x150 px
- However, I must maintain the aspect ration of the image, meaning not the whole of the image will fit into the 150x150 square.
- Since most of the images will exceed the allowed 150x150 dimensions, i would like to focus the display on the middle of the image.

**Some HTML:**

```
<div class="gallery-item" style="height: 232px;">
                    <img src="/media/animals/images/african-buffalo.jpg" alt="African Buffalo ">

                    <div class="gallery-item-caption">
                        <a href="/animals/african-buffalo" title="African Buffalo ">African Buffalo </a>
                    </div>
</div>
```

**Some CSS:**

```
.gallery-item {
float: left;
padding: 15px 15px 15px 15px;
margin: 15px;
background-color: #ececec;
}
```

**View:**

[image]

Comment: So... Do you expect us to program it for you? You didn't even post a http://jsFiddle.net

Comment: possible duplicate of [Resize and crop image with CSS](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21966854/resize-and-crop-image-with-css)

Comment: It may be worth generating the thumbnails server-side.

Comment: Agree with @MadaraUchiha, otherwise users would be forced to download full-sized images which is bad experience especially when the images are very large.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of `img` you can set the `background-image` on divs. If you find that images don't fit well in a square (very wide images), you can change to `background-size:cover`. Idea taken from [here](http://css-tricks.com/forums/topic/square-thumbnail-from-unknown-image/#post-110007), working example [here](http://jsfiddle.net/valentin/WCKKM/103/)

**CSS**

```
.gallery-item{
    width:50px;
    height:50px;
    border:solid 1px #000;
    margin:10px;
    background:url('http://lorempixel.com/100/200') center center no-repeat;
    background-size:100%;
}
```

Comment: That's an interesting approach :) Will give it a shot

Comment: You should use `background-size:cover;` instead of `background-size:100%;` otherwise it will only work for images that have a higher aspect ratio than the wanted image

Comment: I find the first answer from [this page](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1341358/set-size-on-background-image-with-css) elaborates on this well.

Comment: @chadocat thanks for the info, changed the answer to reflect your suggestion