# cannot center and crop image inside a div box

Tags: css, css-position

So I have a `div` like

```
.div{
  width:78px;
  height:78px;
  overflow: hidden;
  position: relative;
  float: left;    
}
```

I want to put random images inside that `div`, I dont know the image dimensions.

If the image is bigger than the `div` , the image should get cropped and then centered in that `div`. And has to keep its aspect ratio.

I have to do this without CSS3.

I tried `position absolute` , `display block` and then add `top` and `left` and then minus the same amount of pixels in `margin`.

```
top:50%;
left:50%;
margin-top:-50%;
margin-left:-50%;
```

I tried `display block` and `margin left, margin right :  0 auto`. I tried without the `position absolute`. I put `float`. I removed it. I dont know how to do it.

Please advice.

Here is a [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/slevin/qeg9jjnr/).

In the fiddle I should see the X centered and the 600 and 400 would be half outside the `div`. But at best, I see the 600 and the X. So the image preserves the ratio, gets cropped but cannot align it.

> ***EDIT***

I would like to do this without using the `background` property at all. Just the `img`.

Thanks

Comment: Also this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11552380/how-to-automatically-crop-and-center-an-image and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21966854/resize-and-crop-image-with-css

Comment: @Turnip I am sorry I forgot to specify that I would like to do this without using the `background` property at all. Thanks

Comment: There are numerous answers in the links provided that use an `img` tag.

Comment: @Turnip All of them use `background-image:` at some point, in html or css, Those who dont, they use CSS3 `transform` that is not fully supported. Thanks